# cargo publish "no targets specified in the manifest"

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I have a library crate and want to publish it on crates.io.

I created my project with `cargo new my_lib --lib`.

My project structure looks like this:

```
my_lib/
├─ src/
│  ├─ lib.rs
├─ examples/
│  ├─ example.rs
├─ benches/
│  ├─ benchmark.rs
├─ .gitignore
├─ Cargo.toml
├─ README.md
├─ config.json
```

My `Cargo.toml` looks like this:

```
[package]
name = "my_lib"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

description = "Does cool stuff."
license = "MIT"
readme = "README.md"
repository = "https://git.example.com/my_lib"
homepage = "https://git.example.com/my_lib"

include = ["./config.json"]

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.4"
regex = "1"
serde_json = "1.0.64"
```

When I run `cargo publish --dry-run`, I get:

```
error: failed to verify package tarball

Caused by:
  failed to parse manifest at `/home/me/my_lib/target/package/my_lib-0.1.0/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  no targets specified in the manifest
  either src/lib.rs, src/main.rs, a [lib] section, or [[bin]] section must be present
```

It tells me to create a `src/lib.rs` file, but it's there!

If I try to specify the `lib.rs` file like this:

```
...
[lib]
path = "src/lib.rs"
...
```

I get a new error:

```
error: couldn't read src/lib.rs: No such file or directory (os error 2)

error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `my_lib`
```

Why won't it let me push my library crate?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#configuring-a-target I believe you need a name

Comment: @Stargateur I still get the same error(s). Doesn't the `name` field I already have suffice? In the documentation, it also says: "This is required for all targets except `[lib]`.".

Comment: I didn't have much xp in pubish package but it seem you choice to opt in to only include specific file and so exclude everything else https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html?highlight=include#the-exclude-and-include-fields `include = ["src/**/*", "Cargo.toml"]`

Comment: @Stargateur WOW, that really did it. Do you want to write an actual answer about this? I'd love to approve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `include`, it's necessary to specify **every** file that is relevant to compilation.

It needs to look like this:

```
include = [
  "src/**/*",
  "Cargo.toml",
  "config.json"
]
```

So be sure to include every file that `rustc` needs to compile and every file that you want to include in your binary.

Credit goes to @Stargateur.